# Why would the Scala compiler consider a type, and the type of a value assigned it to be different?

Tags: scala, types, higher-kinded-types

I have a simple class representing vectors, such that vectors of different lengths resolve to different types. However, I'm having some difficulties implementing the zip method. Here's a minimalised version of what I have done, and the compiler message which I find a little mysterious.

```
  sealed trait Vector[A] {

    type ThisButType[B] <: Vector[B]

    def zip[B](other: ThisButType[B]): ThisButType[Tuple2[A, B]]
  }

  case class Term[A]() extends Vector[A] {
   
    type ThisButType[B] = Term[B]
   
    def zip[B](other: ThisButType[B]): ThisButType[Tuple2[A, B]] = Term[Tuple2[A, B]]()
  
  }

  case class Component[A, T <: Vector[A]](value: A, tail: T) extends Vector[A]{

    type ThisButType[B] = Component[B, T#ThisButType[B]]

    def zip[B](other: ThisButType[B]): ThisButType[Tuple2[A, B]] =
      Component[Tuple2[A,B], T#ThisButType[Tuple2[A, B]]]((value, other.value), tail.zip(other.tail))
  }
```

The error I get is:

```
 type mismatch;
   found   : other.tail.type (with underlying type T#ThisButType[B])
   required: Component.this.tail.ThisButType[B]
```

How come the compiler can't figure out that `T` should be considered the same as `Component.this.tail` in this instance?

Answer (score 2):

Assume it did:

```
// applying some other minor changes...
sealed trait Vector[A] {
    type ThisButType[B] <: Vector[B]
    def zip[B](other: ThisButType[B]): ThisButType[(A, B)]
}
case class Term[A]() extends Vector[A] {
    override type ThisButType[B] = Term[B]
    override def zip[B](other: Term[B]): Term[(A, B)] = Term()
}
case class Component[A, T <: Vector[A]](value: A, tail: T) extends Vector[A] {
    override type ThisButType[B] = Component[B, T#ThisButType[B]]
    override def zip[B](other: Component[B, T#ThisButType[B]]): Component[(A, B), T#ThisButType[(A, B)]] =
        Component((value, other.value), tail.zip(other.tail.asInstanceOf[tail.ThisButType[B]]))
}
```

But then...

```
val zero = Term[Unit]()
val zero0: Vector[Unit]#ThisButType[Int] = Term[Int](): zero.ThisButType[Int] // the mystical double type ascription!
val two = Component((), Component((), Term[Unit]()): Vector[Unit])
two.zip(Component(0, zero0)) // ClassCastException!
```

Therefore something about your code was truly type incorrect and the compiler is right to reject it as wrong. Specifically, the `T#ThisButType[B]` in your code simply *is not* the same as `tail.ThisButType[B]`, since `tail` doesn't have to be of exact type `T` but can be some subtype. In that case, `T#ThisButType[B]` can contain values that `tail.ThisButType[B]` doesn't, which means you can't pass the former (`other.tail`) to a function (`tail.zip`) that wants the latter.

Moral of the story: type projections are evil and should be avoided. You have a perfectly good *value* `tail: T` right there; just project from that.

```
// applying some more minor changes...
sealed trait Vector[+A] {
    type ThisButType[+B] <: Vector[B]
    def zip[B](other: ThisButType[B]): ThisButType[(A, B)]
}
case object Term extends Vector[Nothing] {
    override type ThisButType[+B] = Term.type
    override def zip[B](other: Term.type): Term.type = Term
}
case class Component[+A, +T <: Vector[A]](value: A, tail: T) extends Vector[A] {
    override type ThisButType[+B] = Component[B, tail.ThisButType[B]]
    override def zip[B](other: Component[B, tail.ThisButType[B]]): Component[(A, B), tail.ThisButType[(A, B)]] =
        Component((value, other.value), tail.zip(other.tail))
}
```

The example from before just no longer works:

```
val zero: Vector[Unit]#ThisButType[Int] = Term: Term.ThisButType[Int]
val two = Component((), Component((), Term): Vector[Unit])
two.zip(Component(0, zero)) // fails: don't know that zero: two.tail.ThisButType[Int]
```

and now the code is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I have also tried using `tail`, but leads to different but similar problems, namely that zip wont accept a value of type `Component[X, Component[X, Term]]`. I'm starting to think that this whole idea is impossible, and you just can't have typed vectors.

Comment: ? Perhaps that merits a separate question, but for me at least basic stuff like `Component(1, Component(2, Term)).zip(Component('1', Component('2', Term)))` works. You may need to add extra "proofs" into `Vector` for more advanced stuff, like a `def idemThisButType[A, B]: ThisButType[A]#ThisButType[B] =:= ThisButType[B]` (I think that's true...)

Comment: @Lucas Your `zip` is not actual `zip` that cuts vectors to the shortest of them. Your `zip` compiles only for vectors of the same length.

Comment: @DmytroMitin If a truncating zip is desired, then I'd try for a type-level naturals approach rather than this.

Comment: @HTNW Yes, it works for values, but causes lots of problems with functions that depend on zip. I didn't know I could just tell the compiler things like that, sounds like that might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, it's not quite like `List.zip` etc, I consider it better ;) - well, I would if it worked like I wanted to.